# Developing $\int_0^1 \frac{1+x}{1-x^3} \ln\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)dx$ into series

Tags: sequences-and-series, integration

I'm having trouble developing this integral into a series:
$$\int_0^1 \frac{1+x}{1-x^3} \ln\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)dx$$
Anyone has an idea?

Comment: why is the tag lebesgue-integral ? it doesn't seem related to this question (to me).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make a substitution $x=e^{-y}$:

$$\begin{align}\int_0^1 dx\: \frac{1+x}{1-x^3} \ln\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) &= \int_0^{\infty} dy \: y \,e^{-y} \frac{1+e^{-y}}{1-e^{-3 y}}\\ &= \int_0^{\infty} dy \: y  (e^{-y}+e^{-2 y}) \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} e^{-3 k y}\\&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} dy \: y  (e^{-(3 k+1)y}+e^{-(3 k+2) y})\\&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left [ \frac{1}{(3 k+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(3 k+2)^2}\right]\\ &=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left [ \frac{1}{( k+1)^2}-\frac{1}{(3 k+3)^2}\right]\\&=\frac{\pi^2}{6} - \frac{1}{9}\frac{\pi^2}{6}\\&=\frac{4 \pi^2}{27}\end{align}$$

In general,

$$\int_0^1 dx \frac{1-x^{n-1}}{(1-x)(1-x^n)} \left[\ln{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}\right]^{m-1} =  \left(1-\frac{1}{n^m}\right) \Gamma(m) \zeta(m)$$

Comment: I've noticed that you often put the differential on the left rather than the right - any particular reason for that? :)

Comment: It comes from my background in optics, where I frequently encountered multiple integrals and found it easier to treat the integral as an operator.  I have come to like it a lot better this way.

Comment: Definitely a superior notation for multiple integrals, making it much easier to see which endpoints go with which variables.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{1}{1 + x \over 1 - x^{3}}\ln\pars{1 \over x}\,\dd x:\ {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{%
> \int_{0}^{1}{1 + x \over 1 - x^{3}}\ln\pars{1 \over x}\,\dd x}
> =-\int_{0}^{1}{1 + x^{1/3} \over 1 - x}
> \ln\pars{x^{1/3}}\,{1 \over 3}\,x^{-2/3}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&=-\,{1 \over 9}\int_{0}^{1}
> {x^{-2/3} + x^{-1/3} \over 1 - x}\ln\pars{x}\,\dd x
> ={1 \over 9}\lim_{\mu \to 0}\partiald{}{\mu}\int_{0}^{1}
> {x^{-2/3} + x^{-1/3} \over 1 - x}\pars{1 - x^{\mu}}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&={1 \over 9}\lim_{\mu \to 0}\partiald{}{\mu}\int_{0}^{1}
> {x^{-2/3} + x^{-1/3} - x^{\mu - 2/3} - x^{\mu - 1/3} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&={1 \over 9}\lim_{\mu \to 0}\partiald{}{\mu}\bracks{%
> \int_{0}^{1}\pars{{x^{-2/3} - 1 \over 1 - x} + {x^{-1/3} - 1 \over 1 - x}
> + {1 - x^{\mu - 2/3} \over 1 - x} + {1 - x^{\mu - 1/3} \over 1 - x}}\,\dd x}
> \\[3mm]&={1 \over 9}\lim_{\mu \to 0}\partiald{}{\mu}\bracks{%
> \int_{0}^{1}\pars{{1 - x^{\mu - 2/3} \over 1 - x}
> +{1 - x^{\mu - 1/3} \over 1 - x}}\,\dd x}
> \\[3mm]&={1 \over 9}\lim_{\mu \to 0}\partiald{}{\mu}\braces{%
> \bracks{\Psi\pars{\mu + {1 \over 3}} + \gamma}
> +\bracks{\Psi\pars{\mu + {2 \over 3}} + \gamma}}
> \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\pars{1}
> \end{align}
>   where $\ds{\Psi\pars{z}}$ is the [Digamma Function](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_258.htm) ${\bf\mbox{6.3.1}}$ and $\ds{\gamma}$ is the
>   [Euler-Mascheroni Constant](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_255.htm) ${\bf\mbox{6.1.3}}$. In $\pars{1}$, we used the
>   [identity](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_259.htm) ${\bf\mbox{6.3.22}}$.

$$
\color{#c00000}{%
\int_{0}^{1}{1 + x \over 1 - x^{3}}\ln\pars{1 \over x}\,\dd x}
={1 \over 9}\bracks{\Psi'\pars{1 \over 3} + \Psi'\pars{2 \over 3}}
$$

> With [Euler Reflection Formula](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_260.htm)
>   $\ds{%
> \pars{~\Psi^{\rm\pars{n}}\pars{1 - z} + \pars{-1}^{n + 1}\Psi^{\rm\pars{n}}\pars{z}
> =\pars{-1}^{n}\pi\,\totald[n]{\cot\pars{\pi z}}{z}~}}$ ${\bf\mbox{6.4.7}}$, we'll get $\ds{\pars{~\mbox{with}\ n = 1~}}$:
>   $$
> \color{#c00000}{%
> \int_{0}^{1}{1 + x \over 1 - x^{3}}\ln\pars{1 \over x}\,\dd x}
> ={1 \over 9}\,\pi^{2}\ \overbrace{\csc^{2}\pars{\pi \over 3}}^{\ds{=\ {4 \over 3}}}
> $$

$$
\color{#66f}{\large%
\int_{0}^{1}{1 + x \over 1 - x^{3}}\ln\pars{1 \over x}\,\dd x={4\pi^{2} \over 27}}
$$